# Understanding Caffe code for open source development

Tags: caffe

I am trying to understand caffe code [code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) (both the C++ and the GPU part) as I want to start contributing to it but I am having a hard time since I could not find a documentation and I do not know what modules to read first. It would be very helpful if someone can give me some directions as to how to proceed and what tools should I use for development.

Comment: There is not much documentation. [This](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development) and [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Simple-Example:-Sin-Layer) pages are your best bet. The second one goes over making a simple layer from scratch.

Comment: Maybe a good starting point for contributing to caffe, is adding a proper documentation?

Comment: @Shai for writing a proper documentation, don't I need to understand it first? And can you give some help since you have a lot of experience with Caffe?

Comment: @Prophecies Thanks a lot! These resources especially the second one looks helpful.

Comment: @Deven I meant you can document the way you get into caffe. Keep track of the resources you use, add what you find missing and had to learn by yourself from code...